# RestService is not giving expected result

Tags: android, rest, salesforce, apex-code

Hi i write a basic web service in apex on salesforce.com plateform here is apex code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/gggg')

global with sharing class HelloWorld{

@HttpPost
global static String doPut(){
RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
RestResponse res=RestContext.response;
String body1=req.requestBody.toString();

  return body1;

}


}
```

and i am trying to send a post request to this service using android
first i authorize it and then get access token and refresh token and after that i again get access_token so there is no problem in access token.here is code for android client

```
  URL url1=new URL("https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/gggg");
                                    HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                                    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth "+str);
                                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                                String jsonbody="[{type:QwikScore_Question_Answer__c ,id:a03900000034MfA ,field:{id:Answer_Text__c,value:1.0}}]";
                                OutputStream st=connection.getOutputStream();
                                st.write(jsonbody.getBytes());
                                st.close();
                                    connection.connect();
                                    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                                    String ss="";
                                    String ss1="";
                                    while((ss=reader.readLine())!=null){
                                        ss1+=ss;
                                    }
                                    Log.i("Hello world",ss1);
```

in output response in Logcat for Hello World  i am getting "" as output please point me why i am not getting correct output.i am expecting 
[{type:QwikScore_Question_Answer__c ,id:a03900000034MfA ,field:{id:Answer_Text__c,value:1.0}}]
as output because i send 
st.write(jsonbody.getBytes());
jsonbody as body of the request.please help me how to get correct output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your request you never set the content-type header, so the server doesn't know how to parse the payload.